# Ignore all files of a given type with .Rbuildignore

Tags: r, regex, build, package

I would like to ignore all `pdf` files of my package (including the ones in subfolders). What is the regular expression to write in `.Rbuildignore`?

According to "Writing R extensions", this should be a perl-like regular expression. But the `pdf` files are not ignored when I write a pattern which matches them when I use `grep(..., ..., perl=TRUE)`.

Comment: What pattern did you try

Comment: This will match all `pdf` files recursively `dir(full.names=TRUE,recursive=TRUE)[grepl("[.]pdf$",dir(full.names=TRUE,recursive=TRUE) )]`, hadley's page on packages [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/package.html)

Comment: @Dason Sorry, I don't remember the dozen of patterns I tried.

Comment: @Osssan Yes, but this has nothing to do with the `.Rbuildignore` file.

Comment: From the linked page,  here is a sample entry in `.Rbuildignore` file `^.*\.Rproj$         # Automatically added by RStudio`,. My suggestion was to include the pattern `^.*[.]pdf$` in `.Rbuildignore` file to ignore all pdf files

Comment: Thank you for this proposal @Osssan, but no, it doesn't work.

Comment: I think this is a good question (+1) and not sufficiently answered here. Would anyone who knows the answer care to revisit this site to give us an answer?

Comment: @Mikko In fact I'm not sure my attempts didn't work. Because I "built" my package with the button in RStudio and it is not a "true" build, it is an "install".

Answer (score 2):

For me `^.*\.pdf` worked. I think the `^` starts the regular expression, `.` means matching any character, `*` means possibly multiple matches of `.` (any character), and the `\.` escapes the dot for the file extension.

Comment: Thanks, I will try whenever possible. In fact, I think my mistake was that I did "install" instead of "build" (previously the "Build" button in RStudio actually meant "Install"). And "install" does not take into account the `.Rbuildignore`.